# How to disable blinking screen on 12.04 with Gnome3?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome3. Whenever I press backspace in terminal(no text to delete) it gives me a sound and blinks the screen. I disabled the sound using system settings -> Sound -> Sound Effects -> Alert volume -> off

But I don't know how to disable the blinking screen. How to disable it?

Comment: As a workaround you can disable terminal bell from profile preference in gnome-terminal. But you won't hear sounds on error.

Comment: has anyone able to solve this ? In fact its not just the terminal, same behavior is observed when ever there is error alert.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i just fixed this. Switch off the Visual Alerts. Although gnome accesibility button showed it as off but some reason it was not synchronizing with universal access settings.

System settings -> Universal Access -> Hearing

Make sure Visual Alerts is off.